# Is there any sample for @angular-libphonenumber with angular 2 or higher?

Tags: libphonenumber

I am trying to create a directive for formatting and validating the phone numbers in my angualr 4 application, was looking for some guidance to getting started.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edited (15.03.2018) - thanks @Joseph Webber

First, you have to install [libphonenumber-js](https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/libphonenumber-js), which is a wrapper of google-libphonenumber ready to be imported on Angular 2+.
You can install it on your app with:

```
npm install libphonenumber-js --save
```

or

```
yarn add libphonenumber-js
```

depending on the package manager you use.

After install you can use it on your component like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { parse, format, AsYouType } from 'libphonenumber-js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  asYouType: any;
  format: any;
  parse: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.asYouType = new AsYouType('US').input('2133734');
    this.format = format('2133734253', 'US', 'International');
    this.parse = parse('(0777) 844 822', 'RO');
  }

}
```

I added the working demo on Github:

[libphonenumber-demo-angular2](https://github.com/bogdancar/libphonenumber-demo-angular2)

Comment: I installed using npm as you mentioned above and when i import the 'libphonenumber-js' I am getting the error as cannot fine module 'libphonenumber-js'.

Comment: `asYouType` name is deprecated, use `AsYouType` instead. https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0450--20012018