# Are there any components to format phone number in ionic ?

Tags: ionic-framework, format

I have a phone number in this format +11234567890. I want to show this as +1-123-456-7890 or just 123-456-7890 in Angular5/Ionic. Are there any components available to format phone numbers in required format? Or is there any method to achieve this.

Comment: this can might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019823/is-there-any-sample-for-angular-libphonenumber-with-angular-2-or-higher

Comment: You should use the **Regex**.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/amarkes/br-masker-ionic-3 also, you can create a mask .